# Cannot quit this loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I wrote a simple guessing game which uses while loop.
If user types any word with an initial of "y", the game will run again, but if user types any other word, the game will quit and gives out the report.

```
public static void loopcalc(Scanner console) {
  int totalRounds = 0, totalGuesses = 0, best = 1000000;
  boolean want = true;

  while (want = true) {
    int eachguess = playOneGame(console);
    totalRounds++;
    totalGuesses += eachguess;

    System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
    String input = console.next();

    if (input.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y') {
      want = true;
    } else {
      want = false;
    }
    best = Math.min(eachguess, best);
  }
  report(console, totalGuesses, totalRounds, best);
}
```

Sorry I do not know how to type codes correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You wrote:

```
while(want = true) {
```

You surely want to check if `want` is `true`. So write instead:

```
while(want == true) {
```

Or, better:

```
while(want) {
```

In Java, `=` is an operator which assigns a value to a variable. It returns also the value. So, when you type `wanted = true`, you:

- Set `want` to `true`
- Return `true`

Here, `while` returns gets `true`, and continue the loop infinitely.

Ps : this is a very frequent issue. In 2003, a [famous attempt](https://lwn.net/Articles/57135/) to insert  a backdoor in the Linux kernel used this feature (C language has it too).

Comment: I added an explanation. By the way thanks to @Joakim Danielson who fixed a typo.

Answer (score 0):

`=` in `want = true` is an assignment operator. What you should try instead is the equality `==` operator.

`while(want == true)` or `while(want)`

Answer (score 0):

This is your updated answer.

```
public static void loopcalc(Scanner console) {
  int totalRounds = 0, totalGuesses = 0, best = 1000000;
  boolean want = true;

  while (want) {
    int eachguess = playOneGame(console);
    totalRounds++;
    totalGuesses += eachguess;

    System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
    String input = console.next();

    if (input.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y') {
      want = true;
    } else {
      want = false;
    }
    best = Math.min(eachguess, best);
  }
  report(console, totalGuesses, totalRounds, best);
}
```

You can also try following approach and get rid of want variable:

```
public static void loopcalc(Scanner console) {
int totalRounds = 0, totalGuesses = 0, best = 1000000;
boolean want = true;

while (true) {
int eachguess = playOneGame(console);
totalRounds++;
totalGuesses += eachguess;

System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
String input = console.next();

if (input.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'n') {
  break;
}
best = Math.min(eachguess, best);
}
report(console, totalGuesses, totalRounds, best);
}
```